# How to add properties to a rendered feature of TileVectorLayer

Tags: angular, postgresql, openlayers, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

as shown in the below posted code, i create a `VectorTileLayer` and the `VectorTileSource` is `MVT` geometry that is retrieved from a webservice as stated in the `url` attribute.
the database table contains the columns as shown below. For each zoom-in and -out or dragging event the webservice will be called and retrieve the matching/correspnding tiles according to `x`,`y` and zoom `z`.
what the webservice provides to the `VectorTileSource` is a row of the table `grid_cell_data`.
now, for each rendered feature the function `style` will be called.
what i want to achieve is, to have access to the rendered-feature properties/attributes which are, for example, `isTreatment`, `fourCornersRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON` and so on.
i added logs in the style-function as shown below, but none of the columns in the table mentioned below are accessible. in other words, the name of the columns of the table are not set as a properties to the rendered feature.
the rendered feature should be a row contains all information.
please let me know how to access the feature properties
i also added an image shows the output of the logs mentioned in style-function.

**code**:

```
public visualisePolygonsAsMVTTilesOnMapWithColors(map,keyGridsAsGeoJSON,fillColor,strokeColor,text){
var vectorTile = new VectorTileLayer({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        format: new MVT(),
        url: environment.LocalHostForTileLayerSourceAsMVTTileForZXYWS + "/{z}/{x}/{y}",
    }),
    style: function (feature,resolution){
        console.log("feature:",feature)
        console.log("feature.getProperties():",feature.getProperties())
    }
  });
return vectorTile;
```

}

**postgresql database table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grid_cell_data (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   isTreatment boolean,
   isBuffer boolean,
   fourCornersRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON text,
   fourCornersRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON text,
   distanceFromCenterPointOfTreatmentToNearestEdge float8,
   distanceFromCenterPointOfBufferToNearestEdge float8,
   areasOfCoveragePerWindowForCellsRepresentativeToTreatment float8,
   areasOfCoveragePerWindowForCellsRepresentativeToBuffer float8,
   averageHeightsPerWindowRepresentativeToTreatment float8,
   averageHeightsPerWindowRepresentativeToBuffer float8,
   geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment geometry,
   geometryOfCellRepresentativeToBuffer geometry 
)
```

**contents of rendered feature**

[image]

Comment: but according to my understanding, and as for how MVT works, the returned format from the webserice mentioned in the url should include all the columns names as properties/key in the features..is it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. the problem was in the `select`statement. the `select`statement must contain the columns name as follows:

**query_1**

```
query="""
        SELECT 
            ST_AsMVT(mvtGeometryRow, 'MVTGeometryRow', 4096, 'geom') as result
        FROM ( 
            SELECT 
                isTreatment,isbuffer,fourCornersRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON,fourCornersRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON,distanceFromCenterPointOfTreatmentToNearestEdge,
                distanceFromCenterPointOfBufferToNearestEdge,areasOfCoveragePerWindowForCellsRepresentativeToTreatment,areasOfCoveragePerWindowForCellsRepresentativeToBuffer,averageHeightsPerWindowRepresentativeToTreatment,
                averageHeightsPerWindowRepresentativeToBuffer,geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment,geometryOfCellRepresentativeToBuffer,
                ST_AsMVTGeom(
                    geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment,ST_MakeEnvelope(%s,%s,%s,%s,4326),4096,0,false) As geom
            FROM grid_cell_data where  geometryOfCellRepresentativeToTreatment <> 'POLYGON EMPTY' and fourCornersRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON <> '' and fourCornersRepresentativeToTreatmentAsGeoJSON IS NOT null
            ) mvtGeometryRow
        """
```

the following query is valid but the columns names will not appear as properties of the rendered-feature:

```
query = """
        WITH j AS (
        SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(
            geometryOfCellRepresentativeToBuffer,
            ST_MakeEnvelope(%s,%s,%s,%s,4326),4096,0,false
            ) As MVTGeom
        FROM grid_cell_data where  geometryOfCellRepresentativeToBuffer <> 'POLYGON EMPTY' and fourCornersRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON <> '' and fourCornersRepresentativeToBufferAsGeoJSON IS NOT NULL        
        )
        SELECT ST_AsMVT(j.*) FROM j;
    """
```

**result**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`getProperties()` returns the properties object so `feature.getProperties().myProperty = myValue` should work, but the feature could be spread across more than one tile and exist at multiple zoom levels so that is not a good approach, it would be better to set up an object indexed by a unique feature id (such as the iso_a3 code for countries in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html) to store extra properties

```
const featuresExtraProperties = {};

setExtraProperty = function(feature, key, value) {
  const id = feature.getId();
  if (!featuresExtraProperties[id]) {
    featuresExtraProperties[id] = {};
  }
  featuresExtraProperties[id][key] = value;
}

getExtraProperty = function(feature, key) {
  const id = feature.getId();
  if (featuresExtraProperties[id]) {
    return featuresExtraProperties[id][key];
  }
  return;
}
```